# How I should avoid else if in java

Tags: java, android

I've got to do a check in my android app for orientation screen and after that to set the screen orientation to the next phase. I've run out of ideas how to do that avoiding this ugly else if block of code. Could you please give me a suggestion or something?

```
int currentOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE; // Default orientation
.
.
.
switch (item.getItemId()) {
.
.
.
case R.id.change_orientation:
if (currentOrientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                    currentOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
                } else if (currentOrientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
                    currentOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
                } else if (currentOrientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE) {
                    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                    currentOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
                }
```

Comment: You can use `switch`.

Comment: I'am already in a switch, I will edit the block of code right now.

Comment: you can use nested switch right

Comment: Use nested `switch` (i.e. `switch` inside `switch`)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use nested switch block; eg

```
switch(currentOrientation) {
  case ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    currentOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
    break;
  case y:
    // code block
    break;
  default:
    // code block
}
```

You can know more about switch here: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_switch.asp

Current currentOrientation is of datatype `int` [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE]
others are also of data type int so comparison can be done, if it was of type Object, then we couldn't use Switch

Answer (score 1):

Oops, I did not notice *Android* in your Question. I have no idea whether this works or not in current Android.

---

## tl;dr

```java
this.setRequestedOrientation( 
        switch ( currentOrientation )
                {
                    case SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE -> ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
                    case SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT -> ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
                    case SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE -> ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
                }
);
```

## Switch expressions

You can use switch expressions in [Java 14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_14) and later. The `switch` can return a value. See [*JEP 361: Switch Expressions*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/361).

Note that switch expressions are “exhaustive”, meaning the compiler tells you if not all of the enum values are covered by your `case` statements. And therefore no need for a `default:` case as would otherwise be indicated for [defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming).

I noticed you call the same method in each of your `if` cases. So we can move that to a single method call at the end.

```java
package work.basil.enums;

public class App2
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App2 app = new App2();
        app.demo();
    }

    enum ActivityInfo
    {
        SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT,
        SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE,
        SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE
    }

    private void demo ()
    {
        ActivityInfo currentOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;

        ActivityInfo activityInfo =
                switch ( currentOrientation )
                        {
                            case SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE -> ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
                            case SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT -> ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
                            case SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE -> ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
                        };
        this.setRequestedOrientation( activityInfo );
    }

    private void setRequestedOrientation ( ActivityInfo activityInfo )
    {
        System.out.println( "Setting requested orientation to: " + activityInfo );
    }
}
```

---

Further changes to `switch` being previewed, in Java 17, by the way. See [*JEP 406: Pattern Matching for switch (Preview)*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/406).

Comment: Nice introduction to the Java 14 "switch r-value" :)

Answer (score 0):

Although I don’t understand Android very well, but you can use `hashmap` to achieve it.

```java
//init a hashmap
Map<String, Map<Integer, Object>> configureMap = Maps.newHashMap();

//itemId means all values in item.getItemId()
configureMap.put("itemId", Maps.newHashMap());

//this can replace your if else in switch
configureMap.get("itemId").put(currentOrientation, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

......

Object orientation = configureMap.get(item.getItemId()).get(currentOrientation);
this.setRequestedOrientation(orientation);
currentOrientation = orientation;
```

You can also use `ImmutableMap.of()` to beautify the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map that contains the *next* orientation value according to the current one:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> next = new HashMap<>(4);
next.put(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
...

switch (...) {

    case R.id.change_orientation:
        int nextOrient = next.get(currentOrientation);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(nextOrient); // Change this method so it also updates 'currentOrientation'
        break;
```

Note that it would be more efficient to store those next orientation values into an array, search for the index of the current one and then do a `(i+1)%4` to get the index of the next one. I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score -2):

you can use switch and also use ternatory operator (?) in java.
? operator is used for only 2 conditions. like {condition ? true : false}.
if you have more than one condition than you should go for switch.